# The concept of "average run length" in change point detection

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, data-mining, change-point

With respect to the change point detection for data stream, there is a concept of "average run length", which is discussed in the [CPM package manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpm/vignettes/cpm.pdf):

[image]

I am not clear why that "average number of observations" should equal to $\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume w.l.o.g. that $\alpha=0.05$:

$0.05 = \frac{5}{100} =\frac{1}{20}$

That means that one in 20 values is expected to be a Type 1 error. Since run length is defined as $RL=\min\{i: D_i>h_i, i\geq 1\}$, i.e., the first value with $D>h$ is included in the run length, the expected value for the run length is $\frac{1}{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{20}}=20$.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Can I understand this way? When performing change point detection for a given data stream, I should setup the value of $ARL_0$ based on the pre-specified value of $\alpha$. For instance, if $\alpha=0.001$, which is kind of more "picky" of the test, then $AVL_0=1000$.

Comment: That's my understanding (but I'm not familiar with this kind of analysis). However, pay attention to the documentation. Apparently only certain values are allowed for this (1000 is allowed).